# What does a ruby 'do' iteration loop evaluate to?

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby method: a single `do` iteration without any `break`, `next`, or `return`. Here, `cats` is an array of cat objects; `is_cat_red` evaluates to `true` if cat has a color property of red.

```
def get_non_red_cats cats
  cats.each do |cat|
    !is_cat_red?(cat)
  end
end
```

What does the method return (what does the loop evaluate to)?

Comment: There is no loop in your example, it is just a block.Why can't you just call it and see the result?

Comment: 'do' does not return anything . The method `each` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is some unusual code and it depends entirely on what the `cats` method does. You can pass a block to any Ruby method and that method can get executed *zero more more times* at any point between *immediately and the end of the program's execution*.

The return value is whatever `cats` returns, which is not clear from this snippet.

Imagine this in JavaScript terms as that language is a lot less ambiguous:

```
function get_non_red_cats(cats) {
  return cats(function(cat) {
    return !is_cat_red?(cat);
  }
}
```

Where this shows that `cats` is just a function that, potentially, takes a function. It might ignore your function, too.

Now if this is `cats.each` that changes things as that's probably the [Enumerable `each` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-each) which has well-defined behaviour.

In that case the return value is whatever `cats` is.

Comment: There is no cats method. In this example, cats is the argument of the get_non_red_cats method. Most likely it is an array of cats, but the question is vague on that point. Moreover, if the desire is to get cats that are not red consider instead cats.select { |cat| !is_cat_red?(cat) }

Comment: @PeterCamilleri A more Ruby way would be to support `cat.red?` and then `cats.reject(&:red?)` does it.

Comment: I agree fully, but I wanted to keep the changes to a minimum to focus on the key change needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no loop in your code. Ruby has two kinds of loops: `while` and `for`/`in`. (Actually, the latter is just syntactic sugar for `each`.)

In Ruby, an expression evaluates to the value of the last sub-expression evaluated inside the expression. A message send evaluates to the return value of the method that was executed as a result of the message send. The return value of a method is either explicitly the value of the `return` expression that ended the method execution or implicitly the value of the last expression evaluated inside the method body. (Note that the last expression evaluated inside the body is also what a module or class definition expression evaluates to. A method definition expression however evaluates to a `Symbol` denoting the name of the method.)

So, what does `get_non_red_cats` return? Well, there is no `return` in it, so it returns the value of the last expression evaluated inside the method body. The last expression evaluated inside the method body is a message send of the message `each` to the object referenced by the parameter binding `cats`. Ergo, the return value of `get_non_red_cats` is the return value of the method that gets executed as a result of sending the `each` message to `cats`.

And that is all we positively *know*.

We can make some *assumptions*, though. In general, `each` *should* return `self`. That's what all implementations of `each` in the entire core library and standard library do, and it is part of the standard "**Iterable**" Protocol in Ruby. It would be highly unusual and highly confusing if that were not the case. So, we can *assume* that whatever implementation of `each` ends up being executed, it will return `self`, i.e. the receiver of the message send, i.e. the object referenced by the parameter binding `cats`.

In other words: the method `get_non_red_cats` simply returns whatever was passed in as an argument. It is a pretty boring method. In fact, it is the *identity method*, which is pretty much the most boring method possible.

However, it *could* have a side-effect. You didn't ask about side-effects, only the return value, but let's look at it anyway.

Since `each` is supposed to simply return its receiver, it is in some sense also an *identity method* and thus extremely boring. *However*, `each` is generally supposed to evaluate the block it is passed, passing each element of the collection in turn as an argument. But, it ignores the value that the block evaluates to; the block is evaluated purely for its side-effect. Note that `each` with a block that has no side-effect makes no sense whatsoever. If the block has no side-effect, then the only thing interesting about the block is its value, but `each` *ignores* the block's value, and simply returns `self`.

```
foo.each do
  # something that has no side-effect
end
```

is fully equivalent to

```
foo
```

Another Ruby convention is that message sends that end in a question mark `?` should be used for asking questions (duh!) I.e. a message send that ends in a question mark should return something that is suitable to used as a conditional. It also generally shouldn't have a side-effect. (This is called the *Command-Query Separation Principle* and is a fundamental design principle of Object-Oriented Software Construction.)

And lastly, the `!` unary prefix operator, when applied to something that is intended to be used in a conditional (i.e. a boolean value or something equivalent) is generally not supposed to have side-effect. Ergo, since the message send in the block ends with a question mark, it is not supposed to have a side-effect, and the `!` operator is also not supposed to have a side-effect, we can assume that the entire block has no side-effect.

This, in turn, means that `each` shouldn't have a side-effect, and thus `get_non_red_cats` doesn't have a side-effect. As a result, the only *other* thing `get_non_red_cats` can do, is return a value, and it very likely simply returns the value that was passed in.

Ergo, the entire method is equivalent to

```
def get_non_red_cats(cats)
  cats
end
```

All of this is *assuming* that the author followed standard Ruby conventions. If she didn't, then this method could do and return *anything* whatsoever, it could format your harddrive, launch a nuclear attack, return `42`, or do absolutely nothing at all.